# Fuzzy string compare

Tags: c#, algorithm, string-comparison

I have a KeyStrings list:

```
List<string> KeyStrings = new List<string>
{
    "Can you give me a @key for @key",
    "I need @number of gold to buy a @key",
    "@key\r\n@key\r\nCount: @number",
};
```

In this string we have some KeyWord variable (@key and @number).

On other side we have a simple string

```
var sample = "Item\r\nThis item description\r\nYou can use this item to do somthing\r\nCount: 5";
```

This sample is equal to the KeyString

```
"@key\r\n@key\r\nCount: @number"
```

from list, where

```
@key : "Item",
@key : "This item description\r\nYou can use this item to do something",
@number : 5.
```

I'm already write some method to find value of KeyWords using Regex.

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetKeysValue(string template, string str)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    string pattern = Regex.Escape(template);
    MatchCollection matches;
    int count = 0;
    while ((matches = Regex.Matches(pattern, "@key|@number", RegexOptions.Compiled)).Count != 0)
    {
        pattern = pattern.Remove(matches[0].Index, matches[0].Length);
        pattern = pattern.Insert(matches[0].Index, "(.+?)");
        result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(matches[0].Value, ""));
        count++;
    }
    pattern += "$";
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match m = r.Match(str);
    for (int i = 1; i < m.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        var key = result[i - 1].Key;
        result[i - 1] = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, m.Groups[i].Value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I can't find good solution for search KeyString in list. I trying using [FuzzyString](https://github.com/DavidObando/FuzzyString) library, but in my case strings are very different.

Comment: Can't you just check m.Success to see if the string matches an item in the list?

Comment: I would replace the List<string> KeyStrings with a List<Regex> keyPatterns if possible and I would loop over the matches collection instead of doing the while() loop when converting string to Regex pattern.

Comment: Using regex for every string in a list not a good solution. I already try it, and performance was't good enough.